# Dynamically assign extension based on active disrectory SID with asterisk

Tags: active-directory, ldap, asterisk

I'm new to Asterisk.

Basically all I need to do is set up Asterisk to have dynamic extension numbers based on Active Directory (LDAP) SID. AKAIK the SID is always the same prefix, followed by unique numeric user ID eg. 1-2-3456789-ABCD-EF123456789-**123456**

I'd like to use such number for the extension creation.

Basically the user will log in and Asterisk will give him the extension number same as the suffix ID, so that there could be dynamic tracking of call centre member performance.

Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish, but:

The last part of the SID, that you highlighted there, is the object relative identifier. In other words, if you only have one domain/one AD forest, then yes, you can use the relative identifier. However, you must be aware that there might be a local user that has the same relative identifier but a different domain identifier.

If you're just looking to query all users in a domain based on their SID, then using an asterisk instead of the relative identifier will work just fine.

You might also want to take a look at this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778824(WS.10).aspx), describing the SID itself.